# How do I make this web service work?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new developer and trying to develop a web service in C# by following [this tutorial](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2007/09/all-about-web-service-in-net.html). I did everything as explained in that tutorial, however, I did not get any data from the Northwind database and I got the following page when I pressed the Invoke button:
[image]

As you will see in the tutorial, I did not add the ConnectionString to the web.config file. Should I do that?

My code:

```
public class WSGetCustomerCountryWise : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public WSGetCustomerCountryWise()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod(Description = "It will generate Customer List, CountryWise")]
    public System.Xml.XmlElement
        GetCustomerCountryWise(string sCountry)
    {
        string sConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ToString();
        string sSQL = "select CustomerId, CompanyName, ContactTitle, City from Customers where country = '"+sCountry+"'";
        SqlConnection connCustomer = new SqlConnection(sConn);
        DataSet dsCustomer = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sSQL, sConn);
        sda.Fill(dsCustomer);

        System.Xml.XmlDataDocument xdd = new System.Xml.XmlDataDocument(dsCustomer);
        System.Xml.XmlElement docElem = xdd.DocumentElement;
        return docElem;

    }

}
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest you start learning **WCF** instead of the "old" legacy ASMX web services....

Comment: @marc_s: Not necessarily - for simple task I still prefer "the old ones", because they are much easier to handler (especially for a beginner or when it comes to mono) and if you do not need the "new features" there is no need to make it more complicated then it needs to be...

Comment: @chrfin Microsoft recommends the usage of WCF instead of ASP.NET Web Services. See [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx). And you'll also find some simple examples for ASMX-Style WCF Services. ;) (Maybe have a look at AJAX-Enabled WCF Service eg. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924552.aspx))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to load the connection string with `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ToString()`, but you didn't add it to the configuration (=web.config), so yes you should do that.

Answer (score 0):

For starters; yes, you need to add the connectionstring to your web.config. Otherwise it will throw an exception. You cannot `ToString()` an `null` object.

To find out where your code breaks: what happens if you put a breakpoint at the line starting with `string sConn`? You should be able to find the bug with 'debugging'...

Comment: `null` not `NULL`. This is C#, not C++.

Comment: You're right. I've changed it, but my point was clear I think.